# How to add LDAP data into the queried data from relational database table using spring framework

Tags: sql-server, spring, ldap, spring-data-jpa, relational-database

I am working on web application development using SpringBoot 2.0. The relational database uses Spring Data JPA, and LDAP uses Spring LDAP and Spring Data LDAP.

My web application is authenticated through LDAP and authorization is via Sql Server (relational database).

There is no problem with the authentication and authorization of web applications.

Sql Server can only store the user's ID (to retrieve the user's information in LDAP).

However, the customer wants the web application to display both the user's ID and the user's name (which can only be retrieved via LDAP).

I use Spring Data JPA to get table data from sql server. And I think it is not a good idea to retrieve the user's name from LDAP using the ID of the user stored in the table each time, in order to add the user's name field with hardcoding.

When querying a table in sql server, is there a way to combine user details from ldap using the userid stored in the table? (Like joining multiple tables in a relational database)

SQL Server does not have direct access to LDAP. So I need a way to solve it in the Spring Framework.

I would be very grateful if you could give me a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When querying a table in SQL server, is there a way to combine user details from LDAP using the userid stored in the table? (Like joining multiple tables in a relational database)

Only if SQL Server has some kind of special support for this, possibly through stored procedures or the like.

But you state:

> SQL Server does not have direct access to LDAP.

So the answer is no.

Comment: Thank you, Jens Schauder. I was looking for a way to work around it more smoothly with the framework. But in my current situation, as you said, it seems hard to find such a way. Although it's not a cool way to do it, I think I'll have to find a solution in a way that is more direct-coded. I really appreciate the good feedback.